# Conditional panel not displayed in the userinterface

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

I want my App to allow the user to select the type of plot he wants to graph, based on the class type of the variable selected.

So, this app first splits the data into the different types of the column (in the case of iris dataset, the columns are either numerical or factor), and then, allow to plot histograms or qqplots if they are numerical, or barplots if they are factors.

For this I created two radioButtons options, but it doesn't seem to work, and I don't know why.

The problem is there are no error messages, just it's not displayed.

I've checked that the IDs are different...

Here is the RepEx

```
# Load packages
# Shiny R
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(purrr)
library(DT) # For data table outputs

# Data manipulation
library(readxl)
library(tidyr) # to drop na
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

not_sel <- "Not selected"


ui <- navbarPage(
    tabPanel(
        title = "",
        titlePanel(""),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                title = "Inputs",
                fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
                prettyRadioButtons("data_sel", "Select data", c("All", "Continuous", "Categorical"), selected ="All", inline = FALSE, width = NULL)
            ),
            mainPanel(
                tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel(
                        title = "",
                        br(),
                        fluidRow(
                          column(3, div(style = "height:20px"),
                                 conditionalPanel(
                                   condition = "data_sel == 'Continuous'",
                                   prettyRadioButtons("plot_type_cont", "Choose type of plot",
                                                      c("Histogram" = "hist",
                                                        "Qqplot" = "qqplot"))
                                 ),
                                 conditionalPanel(
                                   condition = "data_sel == 'Categorical'",
                                   prettyRadioButtons("plot_type_cat", "Choose type of plot",
                                                      c("Barplot" = "bar"))
                                 ),
                                 
                          ),
                          column(6, div(style = "height:40px"),
                                 htmlOutput("stats")
                            ),
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # Dynamic selection of the data
    data_inp <- reactive({
        #req(input$xlsx_input)
        #inFile <- input$xlsx_input
        #read_excel(inFile$datapath)
        iris
    })
    
    class_dat <- reactive({
      sapply(data_inp(), class)
    })
    
    class_dat_list <- reactive({
      split.default(data_inp(), class_dat())
    })
    
    factor_dat <- reactive({
      class_dat_list()$factor
    })
    
    numeric_dat <- reactive({
      class_dat_list()$numeric
    })
    
    # Select database
    data_input <- reactive({
      switch(input$data_sel,
             "Categorical" = factor_dat(),
             "Continuous" = numeric_dat(),
             "All" = data_inp())
    })
    
    output$stats <- renderTable(
      data_input()
    )
    
    
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The syntax for your `condition`s is incorrect.  Try, for example, `condition = "input.data_sel == 'Continuous'"`.  Personally, I would use `uiOutput` and `renderUI` to do this because I find the interface with Javascript somewhat unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
"input.data_sel == 'Continuous'"
```

not

```
"data_sel == 'Continuous'"
```